# Does Foreach Item in LinkedList give items in order?

Tags: .net, foreach, linked-list

Does `Foreach Item` in `LinkedList` give items in strict order?

Is the strict order `First=>Next=>Next=>...=>Last` respected in foreach or maybe is better to use `while (item != null) ... item = item.Next`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does.
See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(VS.71).aspx
and how LinkedList enumerator respects the order.

Comment: thanks, tonio. After your indication I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s4xk11f.aspx